# WordPress publish_{$post_type} hook works only for posts and not for custom post types or pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to send push notification when any of posts, custom post types or pages is published. I'm getting enabled post types from the plugin settings and adding action via `foreach` loop in my class `__construct` method. The problem is that it only works for posts and not for any of custom post types or pages. Here is my function and action:

```
foreach ((array)get_option('PushPostTypes') as $postType) {
    add_action("publish_{$postType}",  array($this, 'doNewPostPush'), 10, 2);
}

public function doNewPostPush($id, $post) {
    $pushData = array(
        'title' => $post->post_title,
        'body' => strip_tags($post->post_content),
        'data' => array(
            'url' => trailingslashit(get_permalink($id)),
        ),
    );

    if (has_post_thumbnail($id)) {
        $pushData['image'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id);
    }
    
    $this->sendNotification($pushData);
}
```

`get_option('PushPostTypes')` is an array of post types that user choose, for example: `array('post', 'page', 'custom_post');`

Any idea why it only works for `post` and not for pages or custom post types?

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me, assuming your `get_option('PushPostTypes')` is working as intended (Obviously I had to mock that).

Try a different approach that does not rely on `get_option('PushPostTypes')` to see if you get the same result;

```php
add_action('transition_post_status', function ($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if ($new_status !== 'publish') {
        return;
    }

    // do something
}, 10, 3);
```

Try the `'transition_post_status'` hook that works for all posts without specifically defining them. Put that somewhere just to see if it runs. Do whatever debugging statement that suits you. Then *if* that works, then move it into Class code and see if that works. I'm debugging by trying to isolate where the first thing goes wrong. Keeping it very simple to get it to work, then gradually adding complexity until it breaks.

Comment: I tried replacing `get_option('PushPostTypes')` with `array('post', 'page', 'movies')` to make sure post type values was not the problem but it didn't work for page and movies, only for posts. Did you register action in `__construct` method too? Also did it work for pages and custom post types too? Please if possible can I see your code example that worked?

Comment: Also the thing is that even `'transition_post_status'` and `save_post` actions doesn't works for pages or custom post types. They only work for posts, so I thing the problem is that post types are not registered when those are run.

Comment: Well the add_action shouldn't care if the posts are registered b/c it saves the action to a global variable & only accesses those when a do_action is called. Not positive, but I'm pretty sure posts & pages get registered at the same time, too. It COULD be a life cycle issue, but I can't tell just based on what is posted here. Are you familiar with step debugging? if it was me that's what I would try next. If not, can you post when those two sets of code execute (in the WP life cycle). In other words, what is the most recent WordPress action that triggers each of those pieces of code?

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't make it work at all for pages or custom post types. It only works for posts no matter it's `publish_{$postType}`, `transition_post_status` or `save_post`. So I'm unable to step debug it by removing complexity until it works. However, I checked if actions were registered via `has_action` and detected that `publish_CPT` actions were not registering. Only registered actions were `publish_post` and `publish_page`, but function works only for posts and not pages,  even page action is registered.

Comment: I was referring to literal step debugging, like with xDebug, or your favorite tool of choice (whatever that may be). I am not able to see any issue with the code you posted, so I'm thinking your issue is outside of that. Could you provide more context in your question? Specifically, which WP hooks are firing that execute your code in question? Honestly I'd like to see more of the file you took snippets of your code from. If it were me, I'd put break points on the `do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post );` hook in the `post.php` file in the `wp-includes` folder

Comment: It is very weird, but the code works when I add `add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'addMetaBoxes'), 10, 2);` action hook in code. I don't use any content from meta boxes inside my code and have no idea why it works.